# What misconfiguration could cause Nrwl/NX angular libraries to be affected by parent App?

Tags: javascript, angular, eslint, nrwl-nx

There is an issue with a bit outdated Nrwl/NX project which configuration was not updated to latest.
Too many libraries are being affected via Nrwl/Angular app.

Dependency graph clearly shows double-sided arrows pointing back AND forth to Nrwl/Angular app, meaning this parent app(Nrwl/Angular) changes for some reason affects libraries which are only children and shouldn't be touched.

Due to this issue too often majority of libraries are built/linted/tested.

[image]

Newly empty created Nrxl/NX project does not have such issue and children are connected ONLY downside with single-sided arrows.

[image]

I cannot find what is the main cause for current project.

Would appreciate suggestions/guesses where I should focus or how to approach it in finding the reason WHY parent app changes affect children libraries.

P.S.
Using @nrwl/angular": "12.10.1",

Comment: A last resort option would be to 1) update nx `npm i --global nx@latest` 2) create a new workspace with the empty libraries/applications 3) copy over the git folder from your old project to the new workspace 4) restore only your own ts, html, scss files through git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of this behavior was incorrect design/usage of NX project.
After migrating to NX, up to this point we had moved about 60%-70% of components to libraries, but we had mixed imports between libraries and the remaining not migrated Angular app shared components.

Just by editing single tiny library, which had some-angular-app-component imported and vice versa, that same library being used in some-angular-app-component - The outcome was chain reaction of lots of such import connections, which marked as affected 90%-95% of the NX project.

Always make sure dep-graph shows waterfall connections to avoid such issues and follow NX design recommendations.